# nextjs 14 use avif image from public folder

Tags: next.js

When I try to import avif image I've got error:

```
import promoImage2 from "public/promo-2.avif"; 
// import promoImage2 from "@/assets/promo-2.avif"; // was trying load from assets folder too
```

```
@/components/promo-item:14
Error: Image import "public/promo-2.avif" is not a valid image file. The image may be corrupted or an unsupported format.
```

Image is not corrupted and works find on other servers.

MacOs and Windows, with same version of node js, works fine.
But only on linux server I've got this error.

What could be the solution or what is the problem with linux?

I was trying to run the same application on docker with nodeJS version 18.14.0, but its works find too.

My expectetion  to run build of application on linux server without errors.

```
next info:

Operating System:
  Platform: linux
  Arch: x64
  Version: #1 SMP Debian 5.10.92-1 (2022-01-18)
Binaries:
  Node: 18.14.0
  npm: 9.3.1
  Yarn: N/A
  pnpm: N/A
Relevant Packages:
  next: 14.0.3
  eslint-config-next: 14.0.3
  react: 18.2.0
  react-dom: 18.2.0
  typescript: 5.3.2
Next.js Config:
  output: N/A
```